•/script.js does not exist
I am getting issue of
PS C: \Users\aeshg\OneDrive \React Js> npm run build
> react@1.0.0 build
› babel •/script.js -d lib
babel:
•/script.js does not exist
• PS C: \Users \aeshg\OneDrive \React Js>

In my terminal while setting up babel in vs code
Please tell me how to overcome this issue

Could there be a problem with the installation of babel? Maybe try reinstalling it?

Did you run npm install?

Simply, check if the script.js file really exists, what's its path and how does it loads/imports for the build inside. Then check the module type of the file, it maybe the issue with common or module type of ES module system, or maybe there's a problem with import/require statements in the script. For example, you can't do "require" for the script for a browser, they do not support it (as i know)
